# Is integer and real variables are synthesized or not in fpga?

Tags: verilog

In FPGA, real and integer variables are synthesize or not. If it is synthesized, how to use those variables in varilog.

Answer (score 0):

The `integer` type is synthesizable, but `real` is not synthesizable. `real` is synthesizable in `SystemVerilog`.

You can use it as any other signals: `integer a = 0;`

Comment: How to change integer value? Either using always or any other methods

Comment: Yes, as any other type of signals, it depend on your requirements